# How to use a custom toml file path for Streamlit secrets?

Tags: python, streamlit, toml

Assume I have a toml file which contain secrets at `/some/filepath/secrets.toml`. How do I specify this path for Streamlit to use?

Currently, the streamlit docs mention `.streamlit/secrets.toml` as the default filepath for secrets. However, I do not find any doc which explains how to use custom filepaths for the same.

Comment: Don't know if this is possible at the moment... It seems coded as a constant (first searched in user settings then in project settings): https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/blob/790b3ae6363e4db1a2880b4ceb8eef7fa2d5d384/lib/streamlit/runtime/secrets.py#L41.